# addforce moving diagonally faster

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d, topdown

I am still a novice with Unity and am trying to make a top down 2D game and am stuck with the movement script where the movement is faster when I move diagonally. When I use normalized on the "axis" vector2 and start moving the player keeps moving for a bit and then stops moving suddenly when I stop pressing on any key and when I remove the normalized the movement goes back to normal and the player stops moving slowly and perfectly, but still when I move diagonally it is faster.

Here is my code:

```
{
Rigidbody2D rb;
Vector2 axis;

public float Speed = 400;

void Start()
{
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
}
void FixedUpdate()
{
    movement();
}

void movement()
{
    axis = new Vector2(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), Input.GetAxis("Vertical")).normlized * Speed;
    rb.AddForce(axis, ForceMode2D.Force);
    rb.drag = 60;

}
}
```

Comment: Please use the correct tags! Note that [`unityscript`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unityscript/info) is or better **was** a JavaScript flavor like custom language used in early Unity versions and is long **deprecated** by now! Your code is in `c#`.

Comment: Its faster because using simple maths a 99 triangle with 2 sides of unit 1 does not have a hypotenuse of 1 therefore it has moved further per move.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happens is that the returned values of `GetAxis` are smoothed over some frames. So when you `normalize` the vector it returns a magnitude of `1` for a while even though your input is actually smaller than that since it is smoothing out.

In general instead of

```
new Vector2(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), Input.GetAxis("Vertical").normalized`
```

which always returns magnitude 1 also for smaller input you rather want to use [`Vector2.ClampMagnitude`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector2.ClampMagnitude.html)

```
axis = Vector2.ClampMagnitude(new Vector2(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), Input.GetAxis("Vertical")), 1f) * Speed;
```

which only clamps if the vector has a total magnitude > 1

Comment: oh yeah i see thank you